# Multiple Join query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function getReceiptData($receipt_id){

    $this->db->select('class.name as cname,student.name as sname,student.father_name as fname,
    student.student_parent_email rmail,student.address as raddress,admin.name as aname,fee_particular_name as pname,
    fee_particular_discount as discount,fee_particular_amount as pamount,fee_category_id as cat_id, fee_collections.*');
    $this->db->from('fee_collections');
    $this->db->join('class','class_id = fee_collection_class_id');
    $this->db->join('student','student_id = fee_collection_roll_id');
    $this->db->join('fee_particulars','fee_particular_id = fee_collection_particular_id');
    $this->db->join('admin','admin_id = fee_collection_added_by');
    $this->db->where('fee_collection_id',$receipt_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

this would generate NULL output why?

Comment: In the join try add left in third param example, `$this->db->join('class','class_id = fee_collection_class_id', 'LEFT');`

Comment: nothing would change, same error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using join query, Please use alias like given below.

```
$this->db->from('fee_collections AS ac');
$this->db->join('class AS cs','cs.class_id = ac.fee_collection_class_id');
```

Please try this, This will help you to get output.

Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.
function getReceiptData($receipt_id){

```
$this->db->select('class.name as cname,student.name as sname,student.father_name as fname,
student.student_parent_email rmail,student.address as raddress,admin.name as aname,fee_particular_name as pname,
fee_particular_discount as discount,fee_particular_amount as pamount,fee_category_id as cat_id, fee_collections.*');
$this->db->from('fee_collections');
$this->db->join('class','class_id = fee_collection_class_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('student','student_id = fee_collection_roll_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('fee_particulars','fee_particular_id = fee_collection_particular_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('admin','admin_id = fee_collection_added_by');
$this->db->where('fee_collection_id',$receipt_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
```

}

@Ganesh : Please check my below mentioned query, As per db schema shared by you it's in my local system.

```
$this->db->select('c.name as cname, s.name as sname,fc.*');
$this->db->from('fee_collections fc');
$this->db->join('class c', 'c.class_id = fc.fee_collection_class_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('student s', 's.student_id = fc.fee_collection_roll_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('fee_particulars fp', 'fp.fee_particular_id = fc.fee_particular_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('admin a', 'a.admin_id = fc.fee_collection_added_by');
$this->db->where('fc.fee_collection_receipt', $receipt_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
```

Please change `select()` line as per your table field name.

Let me know if you have any error.

Comment: Please create your fiddle here, so we can help you, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55216

Comment: From whee I can get `fee_collection_id` ? Is this about auto increment id in `fee_collections` table?

Comment: From fee_collections table we get fee_collection_id and this is not primary key and also not set with auto increment key...

Answer (score 0):

```
function getReceiptData($receipt_id){

    $this->db->select('class.name as cname,student.name as sname,student.father_name as fname,
    student.student_parent_email rmail,student.address as raddress,admin.name as aname,fee_particular_name as pname,
    fee_particular_discount as discount,fee_particular_amount as pamount,fee_category_id as cat_id, fee_collections.*');
    $this->db->from('fee_collections');
    $this->db->where('fee_collection_id',$receipt_id);
    $this->db->join('class','class_id = fee_collection_class_id');
    $this->db->join('student','student_id = fee_collection_roll_id');
    $this->db->join('fee_particulars','fee_particular_id = fee_collection_particular_id');
    $this->db->join('admin','admin_id = fee_collection_added_by');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any **sql error** means your query is right but you are not getting data means **your condition is wrong**.

Without see the table structure its tough to say exact reason. By seeing your code look like right but you can check same sql query by writing raw sql query. It seems some table not meet joinned condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getReceiptData($receipt_id){

    $this->db->select('class.name as cname,student.name as sname,student.father_name as fname,
    student.student_parent_email rmail,student.address as raddress,admin.name as aname,fee_particular_name as pname,
    fee_particular_discount as discount,fee_particular_amount as pamount,fee_category_id as cat_id, fee_collections.*');
    $this->db->from('fee_collections');
    $this->db->join('class','class_id = fee_collection_class_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('student','student_id = fee_collection_roll_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('fee_particulars','fee_particular_id = fee_collection_particular_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('admin','admin_id = fee_collection_added_by');
    $this->db->where('fee_collection_id',$receipt_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

Comment: Nothing would change brother.  Output is array(0) {}

Comment: bro send your above table post here.